# Unable to bind function to button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a viewModel with a function

```
 function resetForm(){
        loanSystem("lis");
        status("");
        processor("");
        fileType("funded");
        orderDate("");
        loanNumber("");
        team("");
        borrower("");
        tracking("");
    };
```

And a button on page with

```
 <button type="reset" data-bind="click: resetForm">Reset</button>
```

But I am getting error:

> Unable to process binding "click: function(){ return resetForm}. resetForm is not defined.

But I know my `resetForm()` works because it is called in my `init function` and if I change values in my `resetForm()` it show on initial page load.  Any ideas?

```js
var homeViewModel = (function () {
    var loanSystem = ko.observable("lis");
    var status = ko.observable("");
    var processor = ko.observable("");
    var fileType = ko.observable("funded");
    var orderDate = ko.observable("");
    var loanNumber = ko.observable("");
    var team = ko.observable("");
    var borrower = ko.observable("");
    var tracking = ko.observable("");
    var isLoanSystem = ko.computed(function () {
        return (loanSystem() == "lps");
    });
    var isCalendar = ko.computed(function () {
        return (isLoanSystem() && fileType() == "cancelled");
    });

    function resetForm(){
        loanSystem("lis");
        status("");
        processor("");
        fileType("funded");
        orderDate("");
        loanNumber("");
        team("");
        borrower("");
        tracking("");
    };

    function submitFileInformation() {
        if (!ValidInputs()) {
            return;
        }
        var fileData = {
            loanSystem: loanSystem(),
            status: status(),
            processor: processor(),
            fileType: fileType(),
            orderDate: orderDate(),
            loanNumber: loanNumber(),
            team: team(),
            borrower: borrower(),
            tracking: tracking()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ComplianceProcessing/Ajax.ashx",
            data: JSON.stringify(fileData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === false) {
                    alert("There was an error writing the file to the database.");
                    return;
                }
                alert('Data has been successfully saved.');
                resetForm();
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('Failure');
            }
        });
    }

    return {
            init: function() {
                resetForm();
            },
            loanSystem: loanSystem,
            isLoanSystem: isLoanSystem,
            status: status,
            processor: processor,
            fileType: fileType,
            isCalendar: isCalendar,
            orderDate:orderDate,
            loanNumber: loanNumber,
            team: team,
            borrower: borrower,
            tracking: tracking
        };
    })();
```

Comment: try a `return true;` at the end of the function. i.e., after `tracking("");`

Comment: I added a code snippet showcasing my view model. I tried a return statement but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resetForm` is not exprosed from your viewmodel which makes it esentally private so Knockout cannot find it.

The solution is very easy, just include the `resetForm` in your returned object (which is your "public API"):

```
return {
            init: function() {
                resetForm();
            },
            loanSystem: loanSystem,
            isLoanSystem: isLoanSystem,
            status: status,
            processor: processor,
            fileType: fileType,
            isCalendar: isCalendar,
            orderDate:orderDate,
            loanNumber: loanNumber,
            team: team,
            borrower: borrower,
            tracking: tracking,
            resetForm: resetForm //add this line
        };
```